# Electromagnetic fields and Laplace equations along a square

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

I'd like to solve Laplace equation satisfying the following BCs:
$$\phi(x,y=0)=0$$
$$\phi(x=0,y)=0$$
$$\phi(x,y=1)=9\sin(2\pi x)+3x$$
$$\phi(x=1,y)=10\sin(\pi y)+3x$$
where $0\leq x,y\leq 1$.

I have tried solving it by using superposition, to no avail. The superposition yielded an infinite series whereas the solution is supposedly expected to be finite!

I'd appreciate any advice.

Comment: _superposition yielded an infinite series whereas the solution is supposedly expected to be finite!_ Infinite series may converge, have you checked this?

Comment: It converges but doesn't satisfy the BCs. I have checked it many times.

Comment: How about the point $(x=1,y=0)$?$\phi(x=1,y=0)=0$ or $\phi(x=1,y=0)=10 sin(\pi \times 0)+3 \times 1=3$?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your comment. Yes, what about these points? First of all, is superposition indeed the correct approach here?

Comment: I have just tried re-solving the problem, not using superposition however, and have come up with the following set of equations: $$(1) Asin(k_x)Csin(k_yy)=10sin(\pi y)+3y$$ $$(2) Asin(k_xx)Csin(k_y)=9sin(2\pi x)+3x$$ $$(3) Asin(k_x)Csin(k_y)=3$$ But am not quite sure how to proceed. I'd truly appreciate some guidance! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that instead of $ 3 x$ twice, one of them should be $ 3 y $. In this case, you can use superposition to solve separately the boundary value problem with the linear terms, and then the trigonometric terms, and then add together.. For example, $ \psi = 3 x y $ solves laplaces equations with the boundary conditions $ 3 x $ and $ 3 y $. For the other part of the boundary conditions, I think you should be able to get it :) .